# Can't read a QR code from camera

Tags: android, zxing

EDIT:

After playing around with it for a few hours, I came to believe that the problem is in the image quality. For example, to first image is how it came from the camera. Decoder can't read it. The second image is turned into B/W with adjusted contrast and the decoder reads it great.

**Since the demo app that came with zxing is able to read the fist image off the monitor in a few seconds, I think the problem might be in some setting deep within the zxing library. It doesn't wait long enough to process the image, but spits out NotFound almost instantly.**

[image]
[image]

---

I'm making a simple QR-reader app. Here's a screenshot.
The top black area is a surfaceview, that shows frames from the camera. It works fine, only you can't see it in the screenshot.

Then, when I press the button, a bitmap is taken from that surfaceview, placed on an ImageView below and is attempted to be read by the zxing library.

Yet it will give out a NotFoundException. :/

```
**10-17 19:53:15.382: WARN/System.err(2238): com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
10-17 19:53:15.382: WARN/dalvikvm(2238): getStackTrace() called but no trace available**
```

On the other hand, if I crop the qr image from this screenshot, place it into the imageview ( instead of a camera feed ) and try to decode it, it works fine. Therefor the QR image itself and its quality are OK... but then why doesn't it decode in the first scenario?

Thanks!

[image]

```
public void dec(View v)
{

ImageView ivCam2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
ivCam2.setImageBitmap(bm);

BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivCam2.getDrawable();
Bitmap bMap = drawable.getBitmap();

TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap); 
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
try {
     Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
     Global.text = result.getText(); 
        byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); 
        BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
        ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
        textv.setText(Global.text);

} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    textv.setText("NotFoundException");
} catch (ChecksumException e) {
    textv.setText("ChecksumException");
} catch (FormatException e) {
    textv.setText("FormatException");
}  

}
```

how the bitmap is created:

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
            try
            {
                    this.camera = Camera.open();
                    this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);

                    this.camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                      public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {

                        Camera.Parameters params = _camera.getParameters();
                           int w = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                           int h = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                           int format = params.getPreviewFormat();
                           YuvImage image = new YuvImage(_data, format, w, h, null);

                           ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                           Rect area = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
                           image.compressToJpeg(area, 50, out);

                           bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());

                      }
                    });

            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                    ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the bitmap from the SurfaceView? Are you using `SurfaceView.getDrawingCache()`?

Comment: No, see above. :) But I assume the bitmap is alright, as it is displayed on the imageview.

Comment: can you add the line `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch statement so we can see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code. Returning quickly isn't a problem. Decoding is very fast on a mobile, and very very fast on a desktop.

The general answer to this type of question is that some images just aren't going to decode. That's life -- the heuristics don't always get it right. But I don't think that is the problem here.

QR codes don't decode without a minimal white "quiet zone" around them. The image beyond its borders is considered white for this purpose. But in your raw camera image, there's little border around the code and it's not all considered white by the binarizer, I'd bet.

Still, there's more you can do. Set the TRY_HARDER hint to the decoder, for one, to have it spend a lot more CPU to try to decode. You can also try a different Binarizer implementation than the default HybridBinarizer.

(The rest looks just fine. I assume that `RGBLuminanceSource` is getting data in the format it expects; it ought to from `Bitmap`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just could you please explain, where should I put this TRY_HARDER and how do I try different Binarizer implementations? Thanks again! :)

Comment: `decode()` takes a `Hashtable` of hints. Set key `DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER` to `Boolean.TRUE` in that arg. You see where you're using `HybridBinarizer`? Try another implementation.

Comment: Thanks... I had set it to TryHarder, now it takes roughly 2 seconds, yet still gives no result. :/

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I thought was the issue. Did you give it proper white space around the image, as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I did, still nothing. :) Guess I'll have to implement ZXING like they say at http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ , hope I'll help. :)

Comment: Why would that be different? You're already integrating directly. In general, decoding single images isn't a good way to decode. Decode a stream of them. This is exactly why it's done this way.

Comment: @SeanOwen I am getting the same error, i used `LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap);
          QRCodeMultiReader multiReader = new QRCodeMultiReader();
          Result[] results = multiReader.decodeMultiple(new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source)), hints);` but why sometimes im not receiving exception but the result is just zero?

Answer (score -1):

See this: http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/NotFoundException.html  The exception means that a barcode wasn't found in the image.  My suggestion would be to use your work around that works instead of trying to decode the un-cropped image.

Comment: Well, to make it work i manually cropped the image in photoshop out of the screenshot and fed it into the decoder, just to if it would work and it did work. ( therefor the image is ok ) Are you suggesting me to do so every time I want to scan something??? :P

Comment: In your description you said nothing about cropping the image manually. I assumed you cropped it in software.